# Scala using final static variable

Tags: scala, syntax, static

```
class Foo(bar: String) {
  import Foo.Bar
  def this() = this(Bar) // this line fails, it seems I can only do
                         // def this() = this(Foo.Bar)  
}

object Foo {
  val Bar = "Hello Bar"
}
```

Basically, how do I use `Bar` after I `import Foo.Bar`, do I really have to call `Foo.Bar` every single time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Secondary constructors have outer scope to prevent you doing something silly like this:

```
class Silly(foo: String) {
  val bar = 123
  def this() = this(bar.toString)
}
```

where you try to pass a parameter to the constructor...after creating it in the constructor.

Unfortunately, this means that `import Foo.Bar` is not in scope for that line.  You'll have to use the full path `Foo.Bar`.

For everything in the class *except* the additional constructors, `Foo.Bar` will be in scope as `Bar`.

Answer (score 5):

What if you just import outside the class definition?

```
import Foo.Bar

class Foo(bar: String) {
  def this() = this(Bar)
}

object Foo {
  val Bar = "Hello Bar"
}
```